# program to compare database structures (sqlcompare alikes) for mysql?

Tags: mysql, compare

Do you know of any programa that allows me to compare database structures on mysql?

For microsoft sql, I use Sql Delta, which is really great. It lets you compare, and synchronize, tables, views, functions, stored procedures, and data too. It automatically generates sql statements to synchronize both databases.

I was wondering if there's a visual tool like that for mysql (even better if it run on linux)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout MySQL Workbench - http://www.mysql.de/products/workbench/

It's a free and official MySQL app, available for Windows, Mac OS & Linux. It's perfect for create a database schema, which you can deploy to your database (forward engineering). You can even create a schema out of an existing MySQL database or compare schemas.